# How can I add my apps functionality into other applications easily/legally?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm experimenting with some text to speech applications on android, where my app will speak a pre determined piece of text.

Is there a way I can have other applications use my functionality? For example, if I was using a browser, could I select some text and somehow pass that into an activity in my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define proper intent filters and the third party apps launch intents with matching info, users will be given the option to use your app.

I use the following intent filter to make my URL shortening app available from many places in Android, including the share menus on YouTube, Browser, and Google Reader:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data
        android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

More info available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an intent filter for the activity you want to call from outside. [See here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)